# CSS Flexbox Raster

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I create a flexbox raster which has equal spaces vertical and horizontal between elements while the elements fill each 50% of the width?

The space between the items should preferably be of fixed size (e.g. 3px), but I could live with a relative size (i.e. 1%).

The height should be flexible/fluid, i.e. work for any number of squares/items.

**Notes**

- CSS column cannot be used, since the flow should go from left to right for each row (and not down)
- CSS grid would be nice, but can also not be used, since I need this on mobile devices (which are currently not supported)
- So don't vote down this question, thank you

---

**Preferred outcome:**

[image]

What I have so far is this, but the horizontal spaces are not the same as the vertical ones.

---

**Current approach (not really satifying)**

```
.-webcams {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;


}
.-webcams  a {
    display: block;
    flex-basis: 49.5%;
    margin-bottom: .75vw;
  }
```

Comment: Why on earth did someone give this question a `-1`? This layout is an extremly popular use case among apps like instagram, and yet, the solution does NOT come out of the box from flexbox! - If this question will not be voted up, I will DELETE it!

Comment: CSS column, CSS Grid and CSS Table has a _gap_  like property, flexbox does not. The reason for someone down vote can be many, but since you've been around for a while you should know to post a minimal working code snippet, not only the CSS, which might be the reason. The image is good showing wanted end result, if you add the markup we can _see_ and suggest the most appropriate solution

Comment: Thank you, CSS Grid would be nice, but does not work on mobiles

Comment: Thank you, @LGSon - I added an explanation now to my question. Can you please vote my question up now please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use calc:

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.inner {
  width: calc(50% - 2px);   /* the 2px is the amount of gap divided by 2 */
  height: calc(50% - 2px); 
  background: green
}

.outer div:nth-child(2n) ~ .inner {
  margin-top: 4px;    /* the 4px is the amount of gap */
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">1</div>
  <div class="inner">2</div>
  <div class="inner">3</div>
  <div class="inner">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've +1'd this but it could be improved slightly to make it have a dynamic height too so you can potentially have more than 4 squares. I also added some pre-processing power to make it even more dynamic: https://jsfiddle.net/LzmdzzLp/.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: The height is not fix in the end result, so thank you @JamieBarker! Can you post it as answer so I can mark it accordingly?

Comment: @SimonFerndriger the padding thing seems to be a bit of a hack - what happens when your content is too large for the box? https://jsfiddle.net/LzmdzzLp/1/

Comment: It would be nice if flexbox would have a `space-between` feature to provide the space wanted

Comment: The problem is the flex-wrap causes the issue with your space between, to make it work properly, you would have to have two inner containers, but you still have the issue around what is setting the height for your code - as you have not shown it in your question, I cannot give a full answer

Comment: @pete I believe the height is supposed to be fluid. At least that's what I took from it not being set in the supplied code in the question :)

Comment: @JamieBarker but OP hasn't supplied code for the outer square - that wasn't shown to be fluid (height wise) and from the code for the inner squares - it is taking it's size from the outer square - which mine would also do, but with the fix for his margin problem

Comment: Yes, the height must be fluid/flexible - but the solution from @JamieBarker works!

Comment: @SimonFerndriger If you edit your question to make it easier to understand and give more information, it will give the person who voted negatively the opportunity to remove the down-vote. Perhaps read the friendly suggestion by LGSon in the comments on your question.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a solution because I was asked to by the OP because it supposedly fixes their issue, however it's not a million miles away from what Pete posted and it's actually based upon his answer...

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 400px;
  background: red;
}

.inner {
  width: calc(50% - 2px);
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: calc(50% - 2px);
  background: green;
}

.outer div:nth-child(2n)~.inner {
  margin-top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">1</div>
  <div class="inner">2</div>
  <div class="inner">3</div>
  <div class="inner">4</div>
  <div class="inner">5</div>
</div>
```